# how to implement group by in linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

i have implemented group by query like

```
var query = (from a in Main
             group a by a.Parent into g
             where g.Count() >= 0
             select new
             {
                 parent= g.Key,
                 Name= g.Select(y => y.name).Count(),
                 Contact= g.Select(x => x.contact).Count(),
                 Friends= g.Select(z => z.friends).Count(),
             }).ToArray();
```

where as in the Main am getting the records like

```
In first list  ====>      Parent="1"
                          name="2"
                          contact=0
                          friends=0 

In second List ===>       Parent="2"
                          name="2"
                          contact=0
                          Friends=0
```

But when i am using the group by query i am getting values in this way

```
parent="1",Name="2",Contact="2",Friends="2" 

parent="2",Name="3",Contact="2",Friends="2"
```

And also i need the count of each field.

so please can you tell where i have done wrong,

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There are two output. But there is one query. So, we cant compare the differences...

Comment: is there any other way to implement other the group to get exact out please send any sample code if possible. Thanks for giving reply

Comment: N.B. You don't need the `where g.Count() >= 0` line - groups aren't created if they don't have anything in them.

Comment: You wanna count **distinct** contact, name and friends ?

Comment: You probably want to sum: `g.Sum(x => z.friends)`

Comment: Hi Mr Rawling, thanks for giving replay but its not working can you please send me any other sample.

Comment: Hi Mr. Tim Schmelter  thanks its helped me for getting some solution, but one doubt as i am get the values in a list like main=1,a=1,b=0,c=0,d=0 & main=1,a=1,b=1,c=0,d=0 & main=1,a=1,b=1,c=1,d=0  but at the time of group by i am getting values like main=1,a=3,b=2,c=1,d=0   but i need to get only the last List values so can any one please send solution to this problem.    Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi Raphael no i dont want dinct i want the sum of there individuals, Thanks for giving Reply.

Comment: Hi Thanks to every one for giving replay i have solved the problem i have used g.Max(z => z.friends) in this way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use ToArray() after grouping and expect the same thing.

When you are doing the regular Select-Where query what that will return is an IEnumerable that you transform to an array

The difference when you do a group by is that the return type will be IGrouping which will not translate to the same array you are expecting it to.

You need to handle the output differently if grouping.

---

Suggestion:

```
int nameCount = 0;
int contactCount = 0;
int friendCount = 0;

Main.GroupBy(x => x.Parent).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => {
   nameCount += pair.Count(y => y.Name);
  //etc. for the rest of the counters.
}
```

This way, the selector function that iterates through elements of the grouping will be used to sum up the contacts, friends and names of each element. I hope i understood the context of your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
g.Select(x => x.friends).Count(),
```

You may be confusing the meaning of the `Count` operator. `Count` computes the *number* of elements projected by the query, not their aggregate sum. Thus, if `g` contains 2 elements, then `g.Select(x => x.anything)` will always return 2, irrespective of the values of the `anything` property.

I assume that you mean to return the *sum* of the values projected from the `friends` property, in which case, you should use:

```
g.Sum(x => x.friends),
```